# SwingX AutoCompleteDecorator : no suitable methode found for decorate

Tags: java, swingx

I am trying to test SwingX for the first time,For this, I read the doc : http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/AutoCompleteDecorator.html

I'd like to make a suggestion on a JTextField like this:

```
List items = [...];

JTextField textField = [...];

AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(textField, items);
```

so I create a project on netbeans, this is my code:

```
package test_swingx;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;

/**
*
* @author marwen
*/
public class Test_swingx extends JFrame {

public Test_swingx(String title) throws HeadlessException {

    this.setTitle(title);
    JPanel pan=new JPanel();
    JTextField jtf=new JTextField();
    jtf.setColumns(20);
    List items  = new ArrayList();
    items.add("hello");
    items.add("marwen");
    items.add("allooo");
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jtf, items);
    pan.add(jtf);
    this.setContentPane(pan);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setBounds(280, 150, 500, 200);

 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test_swingx tsx=new Test_swingx("helloo swingx");

 }
}
```

[image]

I get this error :

```
no suitable methode found for decorate....
```

I'm following well the syntax , I do not understand where the error come?
ANY HELPS ?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method decorate call, is resolve to the first method below which is incorrect. Second method decorate expected JList instead of list.

```
public static void decorate(JComboBox comboBox, ObjectToStringConverter stringConverter)
public static void decorate(JList list, JTextComponent textComponent)
```

However, if you still want to use List, you should use this method,

```
public static void decorate(JTextComponent textComponent, List<?> items, boolean strictMatching)
```

I've changed the error part in your question with this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;

public class Test_swingx extends JFrame
{

    public Test_swingx(String p_title)
    {
        this.setTitle(p_title);
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        JTextComponent jtf = new JTextField();
        ((JTextField) jtf).setColumns(20);
        List items = new ArrayList();
        items.add("hello");
        items.add("marwen");
        items.add("allooo");
        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jtf, items, false);
        pan.add(jtf);
        this.setContentPane(pan);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(280, 150, 500, 200);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test_swingx tsx = new Test_swingx("helloo swingx");     
        tsx.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: yes it works very well, the disaster is that there is an error in the doc :O... see : http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/AutoCompleteDecorator.html

Comment: hehe well yeah, if the doc has confusion, just read the source code itself, that should always work. ;-) by the way, i'm using swingx version 1.6.2